# NSFileManager crashing in app delegate

Tags: iphone, file, crash, copy, nsfilemanager

I have this code in a method called from applicationDidFinishLaunching. It works in the simulator, but crashes on the iPhone. There are about 1,600 2KB mp3 files being copied in this operation. If I try to instantiate the app multiple times, it will eventually copy more each time until the app eventually will start without crashing. I am releasing everything I allocate. I have about 20GB disk space free on the iPhone. If I progressively comment out code and run it on the iPhone, the copyItemAtPath seems to be the suspect.

```
- (void)createCopyOfAudioFiles:(BOOL)force {

    @try {

        NSError *error;
        NSString *component;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

        NSEnumerator *enumerator = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathsForResourcesOfType:@"mp3" inDirectory:nil] objectEnumerator];

        while ((component = [enumerator nextObject]) != nil) {

            NSArray *temp = [component componentsSeparatedByString:@".app/"];
            NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [temp objectAtIndex:1]];
            NSString *writableAudioPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];

            BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableAudioPath];

            if (success && !force) {
                continue;
            } else if (success && force) {
                success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:writableAudioPath error:&error];
            }

            success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:component toPath:writableAudioPath error:&error];

            if (!success) {
                @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:[error localizedDescription] reason:[error localizedFailureReason] userInfo:nil];
            }

        }

        [fileManager release];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@", exception);
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:exception.name reason:exception.reason userInfo:nil];
    }
    @finally {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The OS will kill your app if it fails to launch in a certain amount of time. Try doing your copy on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing this all in a loop, the autorelease pool is probably filling up.  Either manually flush the autorelease pool or manually release the memory:

```
NSData data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:component];
[data writeToFile:writableAudioPath atomically:NO];
[data release];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I agree with you and implemented an autorelease pool. The results were unfortunately the same. Then I swapped the NSFileManager copyItemAtPath for the NSData writeToFile. Still, the results were the same. The app crashes while loading.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
```

A stab in the dark, but have you tried using the *non* thread safe version of NSFileManager:

```
NSFileManager* filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting killed by the iOS watchdog, any app that takes too long to launch gets terminated. try calling the method with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`
so that it runs after you have exited the didFinishLaunching method.